# Empty results public user's feed using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I get my access_tokens by using:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&grant_type=client_credentials

Using the access_token I get, I ask for public feeds using:

> https://graph.facebook.com/[obj_ID]/feed/?access_token=[token
>   from above]

For some reason the return value is empty []. The user's privacy settings are public for everything posted.

In other cases (for different users) I get an incomplete feed, i.e not all posts in the feed are returned.

Step by Step to reproduce the problem:

1. Objective: to get the feed of https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000625617939
2. Create an application and using your app id & app secret get the access token as described on [App Login section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (Call https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&grant_type=client_credentials)
3. Call https://graph.facebook.com/100000625617939/feed/?access_token=[access token from above]
4. Result: Empty Json

Is this a Facebook bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: facebook api is used by many and so it will be most probably your problem. which language? could you show some implementation?

Comment: @naveen - I updated the post showing a step by step instruction to reproduce the problem. The problem isn't language depended.

Comment: do you want this feeds from your website?

Comment: The idea is to get the feed from an app (could be a website) without requesting special permission from the user...